# Плавная прокрутка

Tags: c#, wpf

ScrollBar имеет особенность прокручивать блоками по 15-20 пикселей. Мне нужна плавная прокрутка по 1 пикселю (как, кстати, на этом сайте). Как, собственно, это организовать?

Прокрутка выполняется МЫШЬЮ, а не с помощью Thumb.

**UPD:** Предоставляю код как основу для наработки решения:

```
<ScrollViewer>

    <ScrollViewer.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Setter Property="PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Border Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ScrollContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>

                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                           ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" 
                                           Minimum="0" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                           ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" 
                                           Minimum="0" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ScrollViewer.Style>

    <Grid Height="1000" Background="White"/>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Свойство `SmallChange`?

Comment: Это, конечно, свойство полезное, но для thumb'а. Я совсем забыл уточнить, что выполняется прокрутка мышкой, а не "за scrollbar". Для прокрутки мышью это работать не будет (как и, соответственно, largechange)

Comment: Можно хотя бы отключить прокрутку мышью? Только программно -
 используя команды ScrollBar.

Comment: @D.Stark, посмотрите этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676565/218063 Должно помочь

Comment: Или, лучше, предоставьте сниппет разметки, на котором бы я мог сообразить вам ответ.

Comment: @Андрей: Пожалуйста (обновил вопрос).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я немного модифицировал код из этого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676565/218063

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" PreviewMouseWheel="OnPreviewMouseWheel">
    ...
</ScrollViewer>
```

"Застраничный" код:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    int p = e.Delta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - p);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

[image: Mouse Wheel Pixel]

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. А можно попробовать ещё сенсорную прокрутку сделать за Thumb? Чтобы его пальцем захватить и тащить куда надо прокручивая.

Comment: @D.Stark, это штатно должно поддерживаться. Тап, отпустить, быстро второй тап и тащить.

Comment: Возможно, но что если у меня PanningMode установлен в Both?

Comment: У меня по этому поводу есть вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677509/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-scrollbar. Буду благодарен вашему участию в его решении)