# ScrollViewer поверх дочернего ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, scrollview, catel

Глобальный скролл прокручивается пока мышкой не попадаешь на область UserContol'a, у которого свой горизонтальный скролл. В итоге чтобы увидеть содержимое всего UserControl нужно докрутить наведя мышкой.

Вопрос: как прокручивать глобальный скролл вне зависимости от того в какой части указатель мыши? 
(Еще было бы замечательно, если ваш ответ был применим для MVVM)

[image: Шаблон интерфейса]

```
<catel:DataWindow x:Class="VFL_catel.Views.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <Grid Height="auto"
          Background="#F6F8F8">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="ScrollViewerVerticalGlobal">
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <GroupBox Header="Турнирная таблица"
                          FontWeight="Bold">
                   <!--  Содержимое -->
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Серии"
                          FontWeight="Bold"
                          Visibility="{Binding ElementName=series, Path=IsChecked, Converter={catel:BooleanToCollapsingVisibilityConverter}}"
                          Background="#F6F8F8">
                        <!--  Содержимое -->

                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Подробная информация"
                          MinWidth="400"
                          FontWeight="Bold"
                          Background="#F6F8F8">
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <Grid>
                           <!--  Содержимое -->
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </GroupBox>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>                           
</catel:DataWindow>
```

Пробовал через Interaction, но тщетно.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseWheel"
                                            SourceName="ScrollViewerVerticalGlobal"
                                            SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=ScrollViewerVerticalGlobal}">
                                <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ScrollHorizontalMouseWheel}"
                                                      DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False"
                                                      PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Сниппет разметки бы, позаботьтесь чтобы тот кто может попробовать ответить вам хотел это сделать, сочинять подходящую разметку мне, да и другим, думаю, не очень охота. Да и MVVM тут вообще не причем, так затрагивается только View-часть

Comment: @Андрей добавил ссылку примера на github gist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошо. Воспользуемся системой маршрутизируемых событий `WPF`.
Добавьте обработчик у верхнего `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              x:Name="ScrollViewerVerticalGlobal"
              PreviewMouseWheel="OnPreviewMouseWheel">
```

В обработчике напишите:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewerVerticalGlobal.ScrollToVerticalOffset(
        ScrollViewerVerticalGlobal.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: я конечно не знаток паттерна MVVM, но ведь размещение логики в файле View противоречит этому.

Comment: Не противоречит. Эта логика относится к представлению, где ж ей ещё быть.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант через рефлексию, команду и триггер.

Оговорка, использую фреймворк catel, у которого есть встроенный менеджер, но т.к. все примерно похоже переложить на свой фреймворк должно быть не трудно.

**Разметка XAML**

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                      x:Name="ScrollViewerVerticalGlobal">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseWheel"
            <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ScrollVerticalMouseWheel}"
                                  PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <!-- content -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Команда обработчик**

```
public Command<MouseWheelEventArgs> ScrollVerticalMouseWheel { get; private set; }
private void OnScrollVerticalMouseWheelExecute(MouseWheelEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var scrollField = _view.GetType().GetFieldEx("ScrollViewerVerticalGlobal");
    var scrollbar = scrollField.GetValue(_view) as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollbar == null) return;
    scrollbar.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollbar.VerticalOffset - eventArgs.Delta);
    eventArgs.Handled = true;
}
```

Где _view мой  View полученный через сервисы фреймворка.
[Пример для catel.](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Finding+the+view+of+a+view+model)

**Создаем объект команды в конструкторе ViewModel**

```
ScrollVerticalMouseWheel = new Command<MouseWheelEventArgs>(OnScrollVerticalMouseWheelExecute);
```

Comment: А это уже противоречит mvvm. VM не должна знать о view и уж точно не должна лезть ей в "кишки" (рефлексия)