# Скроллинг внешнего контейнера из ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Всем привет!

Есть дерево, содержащее `ListBox'ы`. Когда указатель находится над `ListBox`, нужно прокручивать внешний `TreeView`. Сейчас просто не реагирует.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В листбоксе я отключаю скролл, чтобы элементы сами распределялись по строкам при растягивании всей панели. Когда скролю внутри листбокса основной скролл игнорится.

```
<TreeView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Containers}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:DocumentVm}">
            <Grid>
                <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    ...
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"  />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676565/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, то что нужно, жаль сразу не нашел. Вопрос удалить или можете пометить дубликатом, чтоб проще было искать?

Comment: Закроем как дубликат, у меня и молот золотой как раз есть :)