# Сенсорный ScrollBar

Tags: c#, wpf

Для активации сенсорной прокрутки ScrollViewer достаточно установить `PanningMode` в `Both`. Однако, это не даёт возможности использовать Thumb ScrollBar'а при сенсорном взаимодействии. Как включить возможность сенсорной прокрутки за счёт захвата thumb'а?

Comment: Ой. А что такое сенсорная прокрутка? Это touchpad?

Comment: Нет. Это сенсорный экран. Touchpad у меня с Thumb'ом работает прекрасно)

Comment: Что значит _включить возможность сенсорной прокрутки за счёт захвата thumb'а_? Т.е пальцем тянуть за этот thumb, будто мышью?

Comment: Да. Захват пальцем.

Comment: @VladD: Может быть стоит пойти через стилизацию?

Comment: @D.StarkL Для начала нужно придумать хоть какое-нибудь решение, а потом уже изящное. P.S.: Кстати, по поводу области hittest'а есть какие-то подвижки?

Comment: Можно попробовать, но мне кажется навряд ли.

Comment: @VladD: https://pastebin.com/99wPfEn4

Comment: @VladD: Осталось там подшаманить, чтобы thumb ровно под пальцем шёл, а не отставал. Но это чисто операции типа умножить/разделить/прибавить/вычесть...

Comment: @VladD: Есть идеи решения поизящнее или вполне сносно?

Comment: @VladD: Ну конечно кроме Stylus.Capture вместо Mouse.Capture. Вроде как разницы там не будет (по крайней мере в случае ScrollViewer).

Comment: @VladD: А вот можно ещё значок стилуса поменять? У меня в приложении выглядит как ромб с гранями где-то 2х2 px.

Comment: @D.Stark: Ну выглядит как типичный крепкий костыль. Что ж делать, если само не работает? Должно покатить.

Comment: @D.Stark: На моём компьютере даже нет стилуса, я никогда с ним не сталкивался :-\ Но думаю, что менять системный (?) значок не стоит, юзеры к нему привыкли.

Comment: Кажется, и то я решил: https://pastebin.com/JJVpc5Fs. Предлагайте, если знаете как решить изящнее.

Comment: А по поводу значка: Понимаете, значок под пальцем не видно вовсе. Если только быстро дёрнуть в сторону, он (значок) покажется =) Я бы просто хотел его убрать.

Comment: Скорее всего, это просто невозможно.

Comment: Кстати, не помню, оповестил ли вас. Вопрос по проблемам со стилем окна я оформил: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684475/wpf-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю следующее решение:

```
double thumbHeight, startPos = 0;

private void ScrollViewer_PreviewStylusDown(object sender, StylusDownEventArgs e) {
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(scrollViewer.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(scrollViewer)) as DependencyObject);

    if (parent is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb) {
        thumbHeight = (parent as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb).ActualHeight;
        startPos = e.GetPosition(parent as IInputElement).Y;
        scrollViewer.PanningMode = PanningMode.None;
        Mouse.Capture(scrollViewer);
    }
}

private void ScrollViewer_PreviewStylusUp(object sender, StylusEventArgs e) {
    Mouse.Capture(null);
    (sender as ScrollViewer).PanningMode = PanningMode.Both;
}

private void ScrollViewer_PreviewStylusMove(object sender, StylusEventArgs e) {
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (Mouse.Captured != scrollViewer) return;

    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight /
        (scrollViewer.ActualHeight - thumbHeight) * (e.GetPosition(scrollViewer).Y - startPos));
}
```