# WPF Проблемы переопределения шаблона окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Кастомный стиль окна:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome NonClientFrameEdges="None" CornerRadius="0" GlassFrameThickness="-1" ResizeBorderThickness="0" CaptionHeight="30"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Background="#F0F0F0">
                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- TitleBar -->
                        <Border Background="White" Grid.Row="0"/>

                        <!-- Window content -->
                        <AdornerDecorator Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

В конечном итоге надлежит добиться решения следующих задач:

- Наличие тени у NoResize окон: Для окон, размер которых изменять запрещено, решением проблемы отсутствия тени является установка свойства `WindowChrome.GlassFrameThickness` в -1. Однако, это порождает необъяснимую проблему заметного ухудшения качества шрифта во всём окне (вариант стиля именно такого окна я представил).
- Внешний resize border для CanResize окон: При использовании свойства `WindowChrome.ResizeBorderThickness` resize border занимает положения края окна. Требуется вынести его "за окно" (на тень).

---

Хотел бы добавить новой информации по поводу ухудшения качества шрифта.

В случае установки `WindowChrome.GlassFrameThickness` в -1 действительно, на экранах с довольно хорошим ppi (у меня, например, 136 ppi) этот побочный эффект виден хорошо:

[image: screenshot1]

Происходит это по причине установки тени. Аналогичный эффект мы можем пронаблюдать при помощи этого кода:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Black"/>
    </Border.Effect>
    <TextBlock Background="White" Text="Any text Какой-то текст" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

[Ссылка на ещё один мой вопрос на конкретно эту тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704841/wpf-%D0%A3%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B8-blurshadoweffect-%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)

С этой проблемой встречались многие. Погуглив по сети вы можете в этом легко убедиться. В качестве решения всегда предлагают просто вынести `TextBlock` из `Border`. Ну, верно, по другому вроде бы и не как - ведь всё содержимое родителя с тенью визуализируется в битмап, что отключает субпиксельное сглаживание (никакие `SnapsToDevicePixels`, `UseLayoutRounding`, `TextOptions`, `RenderOptions` и т.д. не помогут). Только такой трюк не пройдёт с окном)

Возможно, ответ на вопрос в том, что происходит, когда мы снимаем стандартный фрейм окна, устанавливая `WindowChrome`.

Ещё просто добавлю, что `GlassFrameThickness` это вызов [`DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea DWM API`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa969512(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61966/discussion-on-question-by-d-stark-wpf----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, мне кажется, я сумел наконец понять проблему)

Задачей ставилось, по-сути, копирование вида стандартного окна Winodws 10 с выноской некоторых элементов на неклиентскую область (хром).

Таким образом, окно должно обладать следующими свойствами и поведениями:

- Наличие **стандартной** тени окна
- Внешний resize border (это невидимая рамка, за которую мы тянет изменяя размер окна - она должна быть расположена "на тени", т.е. за пределами фрейма окна)
- Корректный вид в окошке предпросмотра на панели задач (если вы установите своему окну `AllowsTransparency` в `True`, на Windows 10 по крайней мере, оно может некорректно отображаться в миниатюре предпросмотра)
- Возможность выноса каких-то элементов на хром
- Устранение проблемы "съедания" краёв окна в `Miximize mode`
- Стандартные анимации разворачивания/сворачивания окна

Значит, решение всех этих проблем есть [в ещё одном моём вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675238/wpf-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8E).
**Но** всё же проблемы, поднятые в *этом* вопросе там не затрагиваются.

Как оказалось, решение в использовании [DWM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa969540(v=vs.85).aspx). При установке `WindowChrome` у окна убирается стандартный фрейм, что, как бы, логично. Но нам это, мягко говоря, не на руку. Тогда, чтобы оставить тень, стандартные анимации сворачивания/разворачивания, нужно просто оставить стандартный фрейм, меняя его цвет, вынося на него нужные элементы. Как это сделать, ответ есть [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx).

Но важно помнить, что такое окно не будет выглядеть одинаково на всех платформах (я не говорю уже о Windows XP и более ранних ОС, где вообще нет DWM - он появился только начиная с Windows Vista). Дело в том, что вид стандартного фрейма везде разный, и вам придётся делать его заново в каждой ОС (при этом вид окна Windows 10 вы всё равно не сохраните).

**Другое решение:** организовывайте анимации разворачивания/сворачивания самостоятельно, как и тень (тут надо делать окно `AllowsTransporency`). Тогда у вас возникнут проблемы с миниатюрой предпросмотра (как решить это - не знаю).

**Итог для меня:** К чёрту эту тень. Мне так хорошо.

Comment: Кстати, посмотрите сюда: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpfwindow