# WPF Ухудшение качества текста при наличии BlurShadowEffect у родителя

Tags: c#, wpf

Приведу незатейливый код, демонстрирующий проблему:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Black"/>
    </Border.Effect>
    <TextBlock Background="White" Text="Any text Какой-то текст" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

Качество текста в таком случае:

[image: Screenshot1]

А так, если убрать эффект тени:

[image: Screenshot2]

Вообщем то в сети есть множество подобных вопросов (и на этом ресурсе в том числе), но мне нужно решение **без выноса TextBlock'а из Border'а с тенью** - т.е. чтобы именно **родитель** TextBlock'а имел этот эффект.

Подскажите, как вопрос решить.
Сразу **отмечу**, что никакие манипуляции с текстовым элементом не помогают! Никакие `SnapsToDevicePixels`, `UseLayoutRounding`, `TextOptions`, `RenderOptions` не помогут, применять это дело хоть к самому TextBlock'у, хоть к Border'у, хоть комбинируя. Я думаю, что-то надо делать с самим родителем, а не с текстовым элементом, поскольку именно он виноват в ухудшении качества содержимого последнего.